# Why does this compile just fine (obvious run-time exception follows)

Tags: java

I have a superclass Animal and two subclasses: Cat and Dog. The Dog class has a new method exclusive to itself called playFetch().

Now, I do this:

```
Animal G = new Cat("Tom");
((Dog) G).playFetch();
```

So, what exactly does the compiler think like here before compiling it without any errors. Does it think like..."Ok, Trent is reference typecasting an animal object reference into a Dog object reference and I see nothing wrong in that as Dog is also an Animal and Dog has the method playFetch()" ?

And during the run-time, well...we know what happens. Please convince me why the compiler doesn't complain. Or is my argument correct?

Comment: A cast is a request of the compiler to treat a reference as a reference to an object of the indicated type.  i.e. a request not to complain in cases like this.  Fortunately, in Java, there are runtime type checks so you get a pretty error.  In other languages, you actually won't get an error at runtime...just strange results.

Comment: You have casted it so you take responsibility for whether or not its going to logically make sense. While indeed this case is clearly an error it would not take much for it to be very hard - if not impossible - for a compiler to determine whether or not an improper cast was made. Perhaps you should take a look at static code analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Casting always forces a cast, and it's up to the programmer to use it correctly. Maybe you're trying to generate a ClassCastException for the sake of a unit test ("Cats should never extend Dogs"), or have other plans the compiler wouldn't understand. So the compiler backs off when you use features that tell the compiler to back off, and casting is one of those features.

(That also explains why the spec allows compilers to do this.)

Comment: I dunno.  If that unit test ever made its way into a test suite of mine, I'd ***really*** have to take a long and hard look at how it was designed.  That just seems like a really poor design decision more than anything else.

Comment: @Makato it's just an example (not that there's a problem with using unit tests to prevent bad design decisions)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is thinking it should conform to the Java Language Specification, including [15.16. Cast Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16)

> It is a compile-time error if the compile-time type of the operand may
>   never be cast to the type specified by the cast operator according to
>   the rules of casting conversion (§5.5).
>
> Otherwise, at run time, the operand value is converted (if necessary)
>   by casting conversion to the type specified by the cast operator.

The specification does not require the sort of data flow analysis that would be required to determine that the operand of a particular cast will always be of an incompatible subtype. The definition of a compilable Java program is supposed to be independent of the choice of compiler.

If you want the compiler to know G always references a Cat, declare it to be of type Cat, not Animal.

Answer (score 0):

[The cast is legal by the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1), since a `Dog` is an `Animal`. Specifically, this rule is what's being enforced:

> If T is a class type, then either |S| <: |T|, or |T| <: |S|. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

Mind you, it did say *compile-time*.  The resultant `ClassCastException` happens at run time, specifically when the target class you're casting to is invalid.

In general, you can cast *up* the inheritance chain (that is, a `Dog` is an `Animal`, and a `Dog` is an `Object`), but you cannot cast *down* (there's nothing saying that an `Animal` is a `Dog`, or that an `Object` is a `Dog`).